# forward declaration and cyclic header inclusion in C++

Tags: c++

I have two classes

#### RequestManager.h

```
#ifndef REQUESTMANAGER_H
#define REQUESTMANAGER_H

#include "RequestClient.h"
class RequestManager
{
public:
     void AddReqeustItem(RequestClient *req);

private:
 std::list<RequestClient*> m_reqClientContainer;
};
#endif
```

#### RequestClient.h

```
#ifndef REQUESTCLIENT_H
#define REQUESTCLIENT_H

class RequestManager; // Forward declaration to avoid cyclic inclusion.

class RequestClient {
public:
void CreateRequest(RequestManager* pManager)
{
  // ... I am creating a request.
  pManager->AddReqeustItem(req);
};
#endif
```

In the code above I am getting error undefined RequestManager in Request client class. What is the  problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Split your class definition into a header file (which contains only a forward declaration) and an implementation file (which includes the appropriate header): you cannot instantiate objects of a forward-declared type, nor use its members (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/20984).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a type with only a forward declaration. Forward declaration are used to say to compiler that type exists but compiler does not know the content of the type.

My advice:

- In header file, I would only define class and function members. So forward declaration is possible if only pointer are used.
- In body file, write the code your member function and include the header files

Answer (score 1):

put the member function definition in a source file which #includes both headers.

Or, if you still want it to be `inline` (or if it's templated), then put the definition of the member function body further in the header, after all relevant code is defined. In the case of a single header file (which does make sense here):

```
class B; // forward decl
class A {
  void use(B*);
};

class B {
  void use(A*);
};

void A::use(B*b) { /* ... */ }
void B::use(A*a) { /* ... */ }
```

*Note* the splitting of the code into files (several headers and one source) is only a convenience for the programmer (making it much simpler to maintain and use by other parts of the code), but from the point of view of the compiler this doesn't matter: it sees only one big file of code (after pre-processing). So, it's up to you how you split the above layout into headers and source file.

Comment: You can write inline functions in a separate file (ex. MyHeader.inl.hpp) that is included at the end of the header by adding the `inline` keyword before the signature. So you can use forward declaration in header and include headers in MyHeader.inl.hpp

Answer (score 1):

You use the method `RequestManager::AddReqeustItem()`, but there's only a forward declaration of `RequestManager`. With just a forward declaration the compiler doesn't even know which methods of RequestManager exist. So, to fix this problem, you must provide the *definition* of RequestManager, which is usually in the header file.

Move the method definition of `CreateRequest()` into the cpp file and include RequestManager.h there

RequestManager.cpp:

```
#include "RequestManager.h"
...
void CreateRequest(RequestManager* pManager)
{
  // ... I am creating a request.
  pManger->AddReqeustItem( req);
}
```

Comment: While technically this is correct, it doesn't elaborate on the reason for the failure. @PatriceBernassola answer explains the reason.

Comment: @icepack Thanks for the quality assurance, fixed ;-)